# Silverlight OOB How to throw exception and exit program with Messagebox

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, out-of-browser

In Silverlight Out of Broweser, How does one:
1) Throw an Exception
2) Display Messagebox with the error
3) Terminate the Application?

Can't seem to find any info on the net. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions work in Silverlight as in any C# code.

Here's a simple sample code that should help you.

```
try
{
  //Whatever you want to try
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  //Display error message
  MessageBox.Show(e.Message);

  //Close the application
  Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
}
```